# Using SQLAlchemy, How to filter by association object attribute and Regex?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, model-associations

Using the [`any()` method](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.AssociationProxy.any) I'm able to filter queries like such:

```
session.query(Result).filter(Result.related_images.any(url='result1_1512149119.jpg'))
```

This is filtering for images related to a `Result` class which has a relationship with an `Image` object that is defined by an association object `ResultImages`, such that `session.query(Result.related_images).all()` would return all images that have been specified as related to `Result` entries.

When making first query from above, I get the following output:

```
result1_1512149091.jpg
result1_1512149094.jpg
result1_1512149097.jpg
result1_1512149100.jpg
result1_1512149103.jpg
result1_1512149105.jpg
result1_1512149109.jpg
result1_1512149111.jpg
result1_1512149113.jpg
result1_1512149117.jpg
result1_1512149119.jpg
result1_1512149122.jpg
result1_1512149125.jpg
result1_1512149128.jpg
```

In my database, there are many images for many results, such that the following query:

```
session.query(Result).filter(Result.related_images.any(url='result2_1512149119.jpg'))
```

would return the following data:

```
result2_1512149091.jpg
result2_1512149094.jpg
result2_1512149097.jpg
result2_1512149100.jpg
result2_1512149103.jpg
result2_1512149105.jpg
result2_1512149109.jpg
result2_1512149111.jpg
result2_1512149113.jpg
result2_1512149117.jpg
result2_1512149119.jpg
result2_1512149122.jpg
result2_1512149125.jpg
result2_1512149128.jpg
```

I've read the documentation related to the `any()` function, but am still unclear as to how to leverage it for a more nuanced approach (or if it's even possible). For example, for the types of queries I'm making I'll only ever have beforehand knowledge of the `result1` substring of the filename.

I don't understand why a query, filtered by `result1_1512149091.jpg` substring, would also return `result1_1512149094.jpg`. For my particular use, this is ideal but I don't understand why it works in this way. For example, I'd expect filtering by `.any('result1')` would also return the full list of `result1` images, but it returns nothing.

What I'd ultimately like to do is filter by an Association Object's attribute values using a regex expression, such that I could do `.any(url={{REGEX EXPRESSION}})`. Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'd ultimately like to do is filter by an Association Object's attribute values using a regex expression, such that I could do `.any(url={{REGEX EXPRESSION}})`. Is this a possibility?

Sure is. You can pass about any SQL expression to [`any()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) as criterion. For example a LIKE expression, using [`startswith()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.startswith), [`contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains), [`like()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like) itself, or what have you:

```
session.query(Result).\
    filter(Result.related_images.any(
        Image.url.startswith('result1')))
```

Using regexp is a bit DB specific usually, and you've omitted that bit of information in your question, so I've tried to avoid it in this answer. But you'd use it the same way as the LIKE expression here.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Using `regex` was just a notion I had, certainly not a requirement. I think your approach is exactly what I was looking to achieve.